# elasticsearch filter not working in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using Logstash version 2.4.0.

I have an index `listOfIps` with type `ip` and a single field inside it as `ip`.

I am using the following section of configuration in my logstash configuration to check if the ip exists in my index and copy it to new field.

```
 elasticsearch {
                    hosts => ["1.2.3.4:9200"]
                    query => "ip:0.1.2.7"
                    fields => {"ip" => "ip_found_on_es"}
          }
```

But it is not working. The ip `0.1.2.7` exists on Elasticsearch , still I am not able to get the expected result.
What I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            user => elastic #use if x-pack is enabled
            password => elastic #use if x-pack is enabled
            index => "listOfIps" 
            query => "ip:0.1.2.7"
            enable_sort => false
            fields => {"ip" => "ip_found_on_es"}
        }
```

Try to give specific index, because if you don't specify any logstash will query all indices, which will slow down your work.

One reason might be your index does not have @timestamp attached to each document indexed, and logstash try to get your result sorted based on @timestamp field.
You can disable sort with "enable_sort => false"

Thanks, just let me know if it works or not.